# Why BigQuery Execution Engine Dremel needs to load data from BigQuery File System to local storage before processing it?

Tags: google-bigquery

I tried to dive into BigQuery architecture and got quite confused by the information I gathered about the BigQuery architecture. What is described is that the execution engine Dremel will load data from BigQuery file system Colossus to Dremel's leaf nodes' local storage and process from there. Why the need of the re-store the data in local storage instead of loading into memory and process straight out?

Can anyone help shed some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dremel does not load data from Colossus to local storage, it loads it directly into the memory. If you can point out where it says otherwise, we will correct it.

Comment: many thanks for answering my question. I was referring to this post:https://panoply.io/data-warehouse-guide/bigquery-architecture/. And it says dremel read data from colossus to leaf nodes with local storage, so i suppose it reads data to local storage of leaf nodes in dremel? also are the nodes in dremel entirely sepate from storage nodes for  file system colossus? so basically all compute nodes are separate machines from storage nodes machines?

Comment: I went through that article, and I didn't see where they talk about local storage. E.g. they say "Dremel jobs read data from Google’s Colossus file systems using Jupiter network, perform various SQL operations and return results to the client". And yes, in BigQuery compute nodes and storage nodes are completely separated. Here is a good description: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/separation-of-storage-and-compute-in-bigquery